# Drop last element in list Erlang

Tags: erlang

I need to delete last element in list. I run this code in shell.

```erlang
erl +pc unicode
Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]
```

```erlang
ColumnListWithCommas = [<<"username">>,<<",">>,<<"password">>,<<",">>,
<<"created_at">>,<<",">>,<<"id">>,<<",">>,<<"email_hash">>,
<<",">>,<<"status">>,<<",">>,<<"mess_count">>,<<",">>].
  
lists:droplast(ColumnListWithCommas).
** exception error: undefined function lists:droplast/1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no lists:droplast/1 in Erlang R16B03.
you need Erlang 17.0

You can do:

```
1> A = [1, 2, 3, 4].
2> lists:reverse(tl(lists:reverse(A))).
[1,2,3]

Or

3> {L, _} = lists:split(length(A) - 1, A).
```

And one more way. You can take [realization](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L216) from Erlang sources it is pretty simple

Comment: is there any way to drop element in Erlang 16B03?

Comment: lists:reverse(tl(lists:reverse([1, 2, 3, 4]))) for example